# Validating specific field of an object in Java using javax validation with different conditions

Tags: java, validation

I would like to validate an Object's field differently depending on its usage. I have given a vague example here. I don't see an example for something like this online or in documentation. I am using javax validation. Obviously I cannot add the validation in @Person class, since the min max values will change depending on the use case. One way I could think of would be, to implement the setter manually and invoke my custom validations there. But that would be overkill.

```
@Data
public class Person{
  private String name;
  private String age;

}

@Data
public class OnlineClass{

  
  private LocalDateTime startTime;
  private LocalDateTime endTime;

  @Min(targetField=age, value=30)
  private Person teacher;

  @Max(targetField=age, value=14)
  @Size(targetField=name, min=5)
  private Person student;

}
```

Should I implement a custom validation or is there a way to achieve the same without custom validation?